# Why calling array.prototype.forEach.call() with an array set to THIS object not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, this

Here I have a number array. I tried to test if `Array.prototype.forEach` can be used on array in a different way than the traditional way. In traditional way we pass the THIS argument as second parameter to `forEach`.
Here I used `Array.prototype.forEach.call()` and for this I used the array as argument to call method.
But this indication the window object.
Why is that ?

```
number=[1,2,3,4,5];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(number,function(elem){
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be inside the callback? You're confusing the `this` of the call to `forEach` with the `thisArg` used for the callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because assuming `forEach` has not been overwritten, and this array still has the normal prototype, this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(number,function(elem){ });
```

Is no different from:

```
number.forEach(function(elem){ });
```

In a `forEach` callback function, unless you pass the `thisArg`, the function is called like a normal callback.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `forEach()`, it will be passed to `callback` when invoked, for use as its `this` value.  Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be passed for use as its `this` value. The `this` value ultimately observable by `callback` is determined according to [the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

To set the `thisArg` while using `.call`, you would need to pass one more argument:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(number,function(elem){ }, number);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to forEach(), it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value.  Otherwise, the value undefined will be passed for use as its this value. *The this value ultimately observable by callback is determined according to [the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function](http://%09%20Because%20assuming%20forEach%20has%20not%20been%20overwritten,%20and%20this%20array%20still%20has%20the%20normal%20prototype,%20this:%20%20Array.prototype.forEach.call(number,function(elem)%7B%20%7D);%20Is%20no%20different%20from:%20%20number.forEach(function(elem)%7B%20%7D);%20In%20a%20forEach%20callback%20function,%20unless%20you%20pass%20the%20thisArg,%20the%20function%20is%20called%20like%20a%20normal%20callback.)*.

In the following snippet, we explicitly pass as the `thisArg` the `number` and we have as result that you are looking for.

```js
number=[1,2,3,4,5];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(number,function(elem){
    console.log(this);
},number);
```

Comment: But why would I want to pass in a `this` in this case, since I can get the array anyway as the third parameter to the callback?

Comment: @torazaburo ofcourse Because the value of this would be different if you don't specify it and you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know that jQuery's `$.each` sets `this` inside the callback to the value of the element. But that's not how `Array#forEach` works. Instead, `this` is usually not set, unless the second `thisArg` parameter is specified.

```
number=[1,2,3,4,5];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(number, function(elem) {
  console.log(elem);
              ^^^^  Access element via parameter, not `this`
});
```

If for some reason it is important that you pass some `this` into the callback, then specify it as another parameter to `forEach`, as mentioned in other answers. This `this` will be the same on **each** invocation of the callback; it has nothing to do with the current iteration.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  number, 
  function(elem) {
    console.log("Inside callback, this is", this);  // 42
    console.log(elem);
  },
  42);
```

Using `thisArg` is not that common. Frequently, it is used if an object method is being passed as the callback:

```
obj = { 
  vals: [1, 2, 3],
  message: "the value is",
  alert(x) { alert(this.message + x); },
  alertVals() { this.vals.forEach(this.alert, this); }
};

obj.alertVals();
```

This is an alternative approach to either of

```
alertVals() { vals.forEach(this.alert.bind(this)); }
alertVals() { vals.forEach(elt => this.alert(elt)); }
```