# Why my forEach loop is taking only one value while I have longer HTMLcollection in my variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

```
function clearAllButton(){
    clearAll();
    printId();
    if(markEdit){
       markEditRow.classList.toggle("blue");
        markEditRow=undefined;
        markEdit=false;
    }
    var fields1 = document.getElementsByClassName("red");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(fields1,function(e){
        console.log(fields1, fields1.length);
        e.classList.toggle("red");
        var id = e.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML;
        itemOperations.markRecord(id);

    });
    printTotalRecords();
}
```

This is my code and I have more than one field in "fields1" variable but loop is getting executed on first item only, I am having to execute function everytime for each element. Please help me and please use **JavaScript** only.

> [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3bss2kqytbbtv6u/AAC16GYs4af4JXP1hSVgEBRda?dl=0) is the complete code. But believe me you need to look only this function and only one line according to me, rest you must know better than me , i'm new to this.

Comment: without codes of another function, it is very hard do find the cause. I created a minimal working snippet from the above and it works fine

Comment: please look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40571691/2003642

Comment: you will have to access the element by `this`

Comment: I am voting to close this as too broad because without a complete code, it's unable to process further and you're not responding to any comments

Comment: According to me there is any problem with my base knowledge not the code, please help me if you can.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: @Quentin I have already posted the needed code but people are asking so I gave them a link to access full code if they want, that's it. Please tell me if it isn't allowed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getElementsByClassName` returns live collection. So when you toggle the class you have selected elements by it changes the collection. You could use `querySelectorAll` instead to avoid mutation while iterating.

```js
var red = document.getElementsByClassName('red');

// logs 2 times
[].forEach.call(red, function(field) {
  field.classList.toggle('red') // this line "skips" next field
  console.log(field.value)
})


var blue = document.querySelectorAll('.blue');

// logs 4 times
[].forEach.call(blue, function(field) {
  field.classList.toggle('blue')
  console.log(field.value)
})
```

```html
<input class="red" value="red1">
<input class="red" value="red2">
<input class="red" value="red3">
<input class="red" value="red4">
<input class="blue" value="blue1">
<input class="blue" value="blue2">
<input class="blue" value="blue3">
<input class="blue" value="blue4">
```

Comment: what is `field` in this snippet, if `red` and `blue` hold elements ?

Comment: @k256755 `field` is just a name for element which actually is an input field. You could rename it to anything you want. I like the name `field`.

Comment: No effect dear, it is still the same when I use `getElementsByClassName` But when I use `querySelectorAll` , it works... Thanks buddy. :) @yury-tarabanko

Comment: @k256755 Could you plz recreate the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [here](http://codepen.io/) so I could check what else might cause the problem

Comment: @k256755 Oh, I see :) Forget about my previous comment. Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks buddy... @Yury This was my first question posted here and it's solved in less than 6 hours... thanks buddy, it's possible due to only the guys like you.. :)